# How to add arrays together from form and add them to one field in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop display checkboxes with a value assigned to each checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='rep[]' value='$invoiceID'>Reference Number: $invoiceID<input type='hidden' name='weektotal[]' value='$weekTotal'>";
```

For example if there were 3 checkboxes they'd look like this:

```
[] Reference Number: 1 (hidden value 30)
[] Reference Number: 2 (hidden value 50)
[] Reference Number: 3 (hidden value 40)
```

No if a user selected all 3 checkboxes how do I add all 3 hidden values together to insert that result in a field in the database (so the value would be 120).  Or if the user selected the first 2 (so the value would be 80).  I have tried this on the process page just before the INSERT statement:

```
$totalweek = array_sum($_POST['weektotal']);
```

And then use $totalweek in the VALUE for the insert.

This seemed to work but when I select the first one or the second checkbox on their own then it provides a result as if they were all being added up?

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you print_r($_POST['weektotal']) when it doesn't work as expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the process page use following code:

```
$my_var = $_POST['rep'];
$var = $_POST['weektotal'];
$expense = $_POST['expensetotal'];
$total=0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($my_var);$i++){
$total=$total+$var[$i];
$exp = $exp+$expense[$i];
}
$grand_total = $total+$exp;
```

Comment: This works great.  If I have another hidden value called expensetotal would i just repeat this.  I then would like to add the two together?

Comment: is the expensetotal associated with all checkbox or it is single hidden textbox

Comment: It would be assoicated with all checkboxes.  There is an expensetotal for each checkbox.

Comment: Hello, just a quick question.  This seems to be adding the main figures correctly but weirdly ignoring the decimals.  I assume I need to put a number_format in there to show ,2 decimal places.  Where would I put that?

Comment: ^Ignore that comment, I wasn't passing the weektotal as 2 decimal places. My bad.